# How to calculate the mean, min and max in matlab

Tags: matlab, max, weka, min, mean

So I have a script which calculates the mean from accelerator data:

```
clear all
close all
clc

load 'results.txt'
Fq=51.2;
N=length(results);

t= [1:N]/Fq;

plot (t,results);

role=results;
lowrow=role(1:9244,:);
fly=role(9245:18700,:);
pull=role(18802:28171,:);

subplot(3,1,1)
plot(lowrow)
xlabel('Samples'); ylabel('Acceleration'); title('High to Low Rows')
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(fly)
xlabel('Samples'); ylabel('Acceleration'); title('Reverse Fly')
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(pull)
xlabel('Samples'); ylabel('Acceleration'); title('Lawn Mower Pull')

windowLength = 5; %Length for each window in seconds
startPos = 1; %Starting Position for 1st win
endPos = startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq)); %End Position for 1st win
totalWindows = floor(length(lowrow)/Fq/windowLength);

stats = zeros(windowLength,9);

for i = 1:totalWindows
epMean = mean(lowrow(startPos:endPos,:)); %calculate window mean

%X, Y & Z axis values for each stat
lowrowfeatures(i,1:3) = epMean; 

%Next window position
startPos = endPos+1;
endPos = startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq));
end
windowLength = 5; %Length for each window in seconds
startPos = 1; %Starting Position for 1st win
endPos = startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq)); %End Position for 1st win
totalWindows = floor(length(fly)/Fq/windowLength);

stats = zeros(windowLength,9);

for i = 1:totalWindows
epMean = mean(fly(startPos:endPos,:)); %calculate window mean

%X, Y & Z axis values for each stat
flyfeatures(i,1:3) = epMean; 

%Next window position
startPos = endPos+1;
endPos = startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq));
end
windowLength = 5; %Length for each window in seconds
startPos = 1; %Starting Position for 1st win
endPos = startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq)); %End Position for 1st win
totalWindows = floor(length(pull)/Fq/windowLength);

stats = zeros(windowLength,9);

for i = 1:totalWindows
epMean = mean(pull(startPos:endPos,:)); %calculate window mean

%X, Y & Z axis values for each stat
pullfeatures(i,1:3) = epMean; 

%Next window position
startPos = endPos+1;
endPos = startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq));
end


save('wekafile.txt','lowrowfeatures','flyfeatures','pullfeatures','-ascii')
```

I know the mean, min and max should all be on the one script I am just unsure of how to do this. I will then put this into weka as an arff file to look at the j48 tree.

Kind regards :)

Comment: You can't just dump a bunch of code (not even indented!) and then ask how to perform completely trivial tasks without even mentioning where in your code and on what variables you want to do these calculations. `mean`, `min` and `max` are all built-in MATLAB functions so what problem are you actually having?

Comment: Dan, Thankyou for your response. The problem I am having is in my question :)

Comment: If it is, then it's buried so deeply in unformatted and irrelevant code that no one will ever find it. Read [ask] and how to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In your case you need to focus on the M (for minimal, cut out all the irrelevant code).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but MATLAB has a built in function for calculating [min](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) and [max](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html), just like mean. Use;

```
minimum = min(variable);
maximum = max(variable);
```